# Why is the new Amarok prompting me for Wallet password on start?

Tags: linux, debian, kde, amarok

Why is the new Amarok prompting me for Wallet password on start? How can you switch it off? What is it used for anyway? Its not the kind of software that needs external passwords etc....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the KWalletManager checking for a last.fm password most likely. You can close the KWalletManager from the system tray, the symbol looks like this:

[image]

Comment: +1 Or Jamendo, or Magnatune, if ever logged into them...

Comment: Ahhhh, forgot about these!

Answer (score 3):

[this](http://handyfloss.net/2010.06/scrobbling-to-last-fm-with-amarok-2-3-and-no-kwallet/) is how you can switch kwallet off for amarok